# Pagination System

Tags: php, pagination, paging, infinite

I made this script for my website.

It works and everything but  there is one small problem.

You can go forward infinitely

You can just click Next Page in an endless loop

And for some reason when i echo $num_pages I get 1 0_0

How can I fix the "infinie nexting" - my weird definition for the problem :)

```
<?php
    $per_page = 4;
    $start = 1;
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = 1;
    } else {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    if($page <= 1) {
    $start = 1;
    $page = 1;
    } else {
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
    }
    $next = $page+1;
    $previous = $page-1;
    $GetAllComments = $con->query("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $start, $per_page");
    $num_rows = $GetAllComments->num_rows;
    $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
    while($GAC = $GetAllComments->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<div class='well'> <h3>". $GAC->Title. "</h3>
    ". $GAC->Content. " <hr /> <em> Posted By ". $GAC->PosterName ." </em>
    </div>";
    }
    $pagen = $page+1;
    $pagep = $page-1;
    echo "  
    <div class='pagination'>
    <ul>
    "; 
    if($page > 1) {
    echo "
    <li><a href='?page=$previous'>".$pagep."</a> </li>
    ";
    }
    echo "
    <li class='disabled'><a href='#'>$page</a></li>
    ";

    echo "
    <li>  <a href='?page=$next'>" . $pagen . "</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    ";
```

Comment: put an upper limit on the value of your $page variable (just like you added a lower limit here if($page <= 1) {
    $start = 1;
    $page = 1;)

Comment: I tried with if($page >= $num_pages) { $start = 1; $page = 1;) But doesnt work

Comment: When I do if($page >= $num_pages) { $start = 1; $page = 1;} It only goes to the second page then doesnt allow going to the next one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the display in a for loop:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++)
{
    enter code here
}
```

That way it will repeat for as many pages are in num_pages and not anymore.

Comment: No problem had a very similar issue :)